js: Why so many scroll events?
I'm handling some scroll events, and I noticed that listening to onscroll event fires a lot of event, while the onwheel a lot less. I made a CodePen to see how many events are detected.
In particular, if you scroll the wheel just a little bit, you detect only 1 onwheel, while the scroll generates a lot of oscroll events.
What's going on?

Also check the Note at the top of the MDN page.

From documentation: The default action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a scroll event

Historically, people have used some kind of simple timer mechanism to throttle scroll events to one every 100ms or so.

@Pointy That's not related to OP question.

Please note that when you scroll past end of element, scroll is no longer triggering, while wheel is still counting on

@Justinas I think it most certainly is. If the frequency of scroll events is causing the OP some concern, then general best practice (or "a practice" at least) is probably of interest. And it's just a comment.
